# Somewhat complicated database design for movie collection/library, need guidance

Tags: database-design

I'm a bit rusty on my databases, but maybe you can help out. I want to create a table containing movies bought on, for example, DVD and Blu-ray. As you know there are DVD boxes which contain several movies and each movie in a box can be a special edition, such as a director's cut, etc. You can have both single movies and boxes in your collection/library.

How to structure this? I don't remember the proper notation, but here goes:

```
movies(_id, title, year)
boxes(_id, title, format)
movies_in_box(_*movie_id, _*box_id, edition)
collections(_*user_id, _*id [references either movies or boxes], _type [enum for movie or box], edition, format)

_ = primary key, * = foreign key
```

Does this make any kind of sense?

Answer (score 1):

Your hierarchy starts with a collection, which represents all the items belonging to a user. An item can either be a standalone film or a box set, which in itself comprises several films. I think that the 'format' field should belong to the movie and not to the box (you might have one dvd and one blu-ray in the same box).

There seems to be slight redundancy regarding the 'edition' field but I don't think that's important. If you can work around the fact that you have a foreign key - _*id - in the collections table which references either a film or a box, then the structure is ok, but I think it would be better to represent *every* film as a box set, even if the box contains only one film. Then your structure would be

```
USERS
user_id (PK)
username

MOVIES
movie_id (PK)
movie_name
year
format

BOXES
box_id (PK)
box_name
edition (I assume that this includes the year) 

BOXCONTENTS
box_id (PK, FK)
movie_id (PK, FK)

COLLECTIONS
user_id (PK, FK)
box_id (PK, FK)
```

Comment: I like your design, if I can move `MOVIES.format` and `BOXES.edition` to `BOXCONTENTS`. You are correct that in rare cases a box might hold both DVD and Blu-ray, but a box can also hold a special edition of only one film. I should maybe change the name `BOXES` to something more appropriate, but I understand your structure and agree with it.

Comment: Furthermore, formats are predefined values (DVD, Blu-ray, VHS, Betamax, iTunes and so on) so I'm thinking enums for this, but editions can be the regular ones (special edition, director's cut, etc.) and also user-defined, such as super awesome edition. What is my best option: `varchar` or another table?

Comment: There will also be some redundancy for single movies as their titles are entered the same way two times: in both `MOVIES` and `BOXES`.

Comment: @Viktor: regarding your comment about formats and editions. The choice between enums and a table depends on the amount of change one expects to see. Once a movie was only available on Betamax - but then it became available on VHS, DVD, etc. Every time a new format appears, the stronger the case becomes for having a table, as adding a format in a table will not require a change in the db structure. This (a table) is probably the best way to go for editions as well, as their names are less standardised.